# I cannot understand Sobel & Crawford 1982 (cheap talk)

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game

I am a master student, currently reading this paper for fun during the break. I got lost during the part $U^S(\bar y, \bar m, b) = \max_{y \in Y} U^S(y,\bar m, b)$ on page 5. I dont understand why they wrote this without any explanation. Then I got lost again during proof of lemma 1. Should I read other paper first before approaching this?${{}}$

Comment: One way to go through CS 1982 is to reproduce the proofs with simple examples. e.g. $\theta\sim U[0,1]$, $u^S=-(\theta-y-b)^2$, and $u^B=-(\theta-y)^2$.

Answer (score 5):

$U^S(\bar y,\bar m,b)=\max_{y\in Y}U^S(y,\bar m,b)$ is standard notation that says $\bar y$ is the action (taken by receiver) that would maximize sender's utility given message $\bar m$ and bias parameter $b$. In other words, sender would prefer receiver to choose $\bar y$ when he sends message $\bar m$. Sender's maximized utility is $U^S(\bar y,\bar m,b)$.

For a simpler introduction to Crawford and Sobel, you can read Chapter 18 of [Tadelis's Game Theory textbook](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Game_Theory.html?id=_4OqAaITAWMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) on cheap talk games.